# Draw a Venn diagram for: (A $\subseteq$ B) $\Rightarrow$ C $\cap$ A $\subseteq$ C $\cap$ B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let M be an arbitrary set and let A, B, C ⊆ M be subsets of M. Prove or use a counterexample to disprove the validity of the following statement:

(A $\subseteq$ B) $\Rightarrow$ C $\cap$ A $\subseteq$ C $\cap$ B

I **don’t know where to start with this kind of “subset/implies” statements** and I can’t find something similar in textbooks/online.

The statement is valid.

I’m trying to draw a Venn diagram to see for myself first if the statment is valid or not, before proceeding further. **But I’m not succeeding at visualizing it.**

I’m looking for inputs on how it should look like.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A \subset B$, any point of $A$ lays in $B$. Since any point of $A \cap C$ lays in $A$ and in $C$, any point of $A\cap C$ is also inside $B$ and $C$, which means its in $B \cap C$. 
[image]